# How to make full use of multiple processors?

Tags: java, multithreading, web-crawler, multiprocessing

I am doing web crawling on a server with 32 virtual processors using Java. How can I make full of these processors? I've seen some suggestions on multi-threaded programming, but I wonder how that could ensure all processors would be taken advantage of since we can do multi-threaded programming on single processor machine as well.

Comment: Multithread on single processor machine doesn't have any effect beyond fill in the time that IO operation is taking place (a thread for blocking IO operation, another thread to respond to user). For multiple processor, if you have a task and split it up for multiple processors to work on, then it will be faster by having multiple processors working at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no simple answer to this ... except the way to ensure all processors are used is to use multi-threading *the right way*.  (Note: that is a circular answer!)

Basically, the way to get effective use of multiple processors is to:

- ensure that there is work that can be done in parallel, and
- reduce / eliminate contention points that force one thread to wait while another thread does something.

This is difficult enough when you are doing simple computation.  For a web crawler, you've got the additional problems that the threads will be competing for network and (possibly) remove server bandwidth, and they will typically be attempting to put their results into a shared data structure or database.

That's about all that can be said at this level of generality ...

---

And as @veer correctly points, you can't "ensure" it.

---

> ... but using a load of threads will surely be quicker wall-time-wise because all the miserable network latency will happen in parallel ...

Actually, if you go overboard, a load of threads can *reduce* throughput because of contention.  Just throwing lots of threads at the problem is rarely a good idea.

Comment: +1 Parsing a web page for links is CPU-intensive but fairly simple and quick.  DNS lookups and fetching the pages is really slow.  I very much doubt that OP will be able to use up 100% CPU, but using a load of threads will surely be quicker wall-time-wise because all the miserable network latency will happen in parallel, (assuming, as you say, that the O/P is handled efficiently - chunking up file writes, DB batch-inserts etc.

Answer (score 0):

A computer or a program is only as fast as the slowest link in its processing chain. Just increasing the CPU capacity is not going to ensure a drastic performance peak. Leaving aside other issues like your cache-size, RAM, etc., there are two basic kinds of approach to your question about how to take advantage of all your processors:

[1] Using a Jit/just-in-time compiler/interpreter technology such as Java/.NET. I don't know much about java, but the .NET jitter is definitely designed to take advantage of all the available processors on the mahcine. In fact, this very feature makes a jitter stand out against other static language compilers like C/C++, because the jitter "knows" that it is sitting on 32 processors, it is in a much better position to take advantage of them than a program statically compiled on any other machine. (provided you have written a robust multi-threading code for it!)

[2] Programming in C/C++. This is the classic approach. If you compile your code on the same machine with 32 CPUs, and take proper care in your program such as memory-management, handling pointers, etc. the C/C++ program will be the most optimal and will perform better than its CLR/JVM counterpart (as it runs without the extra overhead of a garbage-collector or a VM).

But keep in mind that writing robust code is much easier in .NET/Java than C/C++. So, if you are not a "hard-core" programmer, I would suggest going with the former approach. Also remember to handle your multiple threads with care, such as locking variables when multiple threads try to change the same variables. However, excessive locking might make your code hang, if a variable behaves unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

Processor management is implemented in native through the Virtual machine you are using i.e., JVM. You can have a look here [Java Hotspot VM Options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) to optimize your machine if you are using Java Hotspot VM. If you are using a third party VM then your provider may help you with tuning it for your requirements.

Application performance in design practically depends on you.
If you would like to monitor your threads and memory usage to optimize your application, you can use any VM monitoring tools available to date. The Java virtual machine (JVM) has built-in instrumentation that enables you to monitor and manage it using JMX.
For details you can check [Platform Monitoring and management using JMX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/agent.html). For third party VMs you have to contact the vendor I guess.